# Data Import Handler in Solr

Tags: java, mysql, solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying the Data Import Handler for MySQL Database.

I added the DIhandler in solrconfig.xml, created a data-config.xml according to my database scheme and also added a field in the schema.xml which was different. I am connecting with MySQL database

After i connect and I run the `dataimport?command=full-import` i get this response

```
"00C:\solr\conf\data-config.xmlfull-importidle1102011-03-05 15:01:04Indexing completed.    Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.2011-03-05 15:01:042011-03-05  15:01:040:0:0.400This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future."
```

The xml files are in this http://pastebin.com/iKebKGSZ

Comment: Can you find any error messages in server's log? I'm not really sure you can use backslashes when specifying the `config` param of `data import handler`. Since it's in your `conf` directory, you can only specify the file name: <str name="config">data-config.xml</str> What happens when you click on `Document count` action on data import page?

Comment: Please post your data config file. It is probably just a simple connection issue.

Comment: Yeah, maybe provide a relative path to the config file rather than the Windows format absolute path

Comment: Try running the queries which are there in config, which you use to check if you really get results from those queries

Answer (score 1):

```
<field column="manu" name="manu" />
<field column="id" name="id" />
<field column="weight" name="weight" />
<field column="price" name="price" />
<field column="popularity" name="popularity" />
<field column="instock" name="inStock" />
<field column="includes" name="includes" />
```

Are these fields also in your `schema.xml`?

I couldnt see them in the pastebin link. Make sure you have all fields in your schema as well.